# xcode/perlbrew & building CPAN modules - make options? SDKs? Getting build errors

Tags: xcode, macos, perl, cpan, perlbrew

I'm brand new to OSX, but have been using UNIX/Linux for decades. Just got a new MBP Retina running latest OSX 10.8.1.

- installed fink
- installed perlbrew
- installed xcode

All's well, except I can't get a lot of CPAN modules to build. I am guessing I need to add some magic xcode SDK to get needed libs?

Here's an example:

```
$ cpanm Wx
...
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/dfelicia/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/lib/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/cc_runtime.h', needed by `RichText.o'.  
Stop.
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 2
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
```

Regardless of the module that fails to build (and there are many), the failure is always with cc_runtime.h.

What am I missing?

I built perl 5.16.2 using the perlbrew arguments from here: http://wiki.wxperl.info/w/index.php/Mac_OS_X_Platform_Notes

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha. I figured out that fink was injecting its perl into the shell env (PERL5LIB, PERLHOME, @INC, etc.). How annoying. I ditched fink and am using Mac Ports, instead.

Anyhow, with a clean env I am able to build everything.

Answer (score 0):

Guesswork on my side as I've never really gotten into OSX:

Have you tried installing MakeMaker as suggested [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=906346)? Sounds like it could make sense if you have a lot of failures.

CPAN should do that for you though...